# Best way to store list of activities to be called from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have following goal: From a list in main activity that extends ListActivity, I want to start other activities.

This is the code of the main activity:

```
public class SelectionWidgetsExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

    private Class[] demos = {ListViewDemo.class, ChecklistDemo.class};
    private ArrayAdapter<Class> aa;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<Class>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, demos);
        setListAdapter(aa);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, demos[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My question is

**How would you solve the issue of having list of classes to be executed outside the code of the main activity?**

My first idea was to put it into xml resource file as string array. I can then easily create array of Strings from the resource, but don't know how to convert the string to the class - I need something like:

```
    SomeJavaClass.getMeClassFromString(demos[position])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need [Class#forName(String className)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)?
It will solve your issue.
  But what's wrong with your initial (posted) solution? I'd rather keep it than use dynamic class loading, only would changed modifiers of `demos` to `private static final`.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if using the Class type wasn't some bad practice. Also, I get a warning in the line where i declare `Class[] demos` saying Class is raw type, and I should use generics. However, when I change it to `Class<Activity>[] demos = {...};` I get an error saying *Cannot create generic array of Class<Activity>*.

Comment: Interesting point. Searched a bit and found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749425/how-do-i-use-generics-with-an-array-of-classes. However, in your case I'd use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` since you don't care of actual class as they will be predefined and won't be even casted to `Activity`.