# Array of Generic Interface

Tags: java, generics

Can we create array of generic interface in java?

```
interface Sample<T>{}
```

in other class

```
Sample<T> s[] = new Sample[2] ; // for this it shows warning

Sample<T> s[] = new Sample<T>[2];// for this it shows error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics and array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470198/java-generics-and-array-initialization)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to: Generic Array creation ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Java does not support creation of generic arrays. I do not know the exact reason. Actually generics exist at compile time only and are removed when you run javac, i.e. move from .java to .class. But it is not enough to understand the limitation. Probably they had some backwards compatibility problems with such feature.

Here are the workarounds you can use.

1. Use collections (e.g. list) instead of array.

   ```
   List<Sameple> list = new ArrayList<Sameple>(); // this is OK and typesafe
   ```
2. Create array without generics, put the code into special factory method annotated with `@SuppressWarnings`:

   ```
   public class Test {
       interface Sample<T>{}
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public static <T> Sample<T>[] sampleArray() {
           return new Sample[2];
       }
   }
   ```

Now you can use this factory method without any additional warning.

**General tip.**

It is bad practice to suppress warnings. Warnings are potential problems. So if I have to suppress warning I at least try to decrease the scope where the warning is suppressed. 
Unfortunately legacy java APIs do not support generics. We often get warnings when we use such APIs. I am always trying to localize such uses into special classes or at least methods like `sampelArray()`. These methods are marked by `@SuppressWarning` and often contain comment that explain why warnings are suppressed here.