# Creating an array(?) of Sets in Java

Tags: java, declaration

I'm trying to write an algorithm that finds the number of solutions in a given partially filled in Sudoku board. i.e. given

```
"1 6 4 0 0 0 0 0 2",
"2 0 0 4 0 3 9 1 0",
"0 0 5 0 8 0 4 0 7",
"0 9 0 0 0 6 5 0 0",
"5 0 0 1 0 2 0 0 8",
"0 0 8 9 0 0 0 3 0",
"8 0 9 0 4 0 2 0 0",
"0 7 3 5 0 9 0 0 1",
"4 0 0 0 0 0 6 7 9"
```

where 0s represent blank spots. I want to create 3 separate arrays of sets, one for each set of numbers in each column, row, and 3x3 square. I am trying the declaration:

```
horizontal = new HashSet<Integer>[9];
```

Where private HashSet[] horizontal is declared earlier, but this doesn't work. What is the correct declaration or can I not make declare an array of Sets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of Generic Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975054/array-of-generic-interface)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to: Generic Array creation ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the type parameter.  You can't create generic arrays in Java.  You can remove the type parameter and it will work, but you should get a warning about unchecked operations.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
horizontal = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer>>();
```

Access it with `horizontal.get(1);` and you can treat it the same way as a normal array. As @user599152 said, you can't create generic arrays. So you need to figure out another way. A list is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

An array of sets is a strange way to store the data.  A 2d array or a 2d array of 2d arrays might be a much more intuitive way of modeling this.   Possibly even a 2d array of some custom class ("SudokuCube") would also work better than an array of sets.