# Why array instantiation with a generic type does not work in Java?

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface Foo<E> {

    public void blah(E e);

}

public class MyClass<E> {

    private final Foo<E>[] fooArray = new Foo<E>[8]; // does not compile!

    // (...)

}
```

What is the correct way of addressing that generics limitation?

Or maybe it is not a limitation and I am missing something?

Comment: What if you try "new Foo<Integer>[8]" to see what happens?  Your instantiation will need to be concrete.

Comment: @JamesBlack if you try `new Foo<Integer>[8]` you'll still get a compile error

Comment: @chrisapotek do not add such things like *this is not a duplicate* in question, that kind of edits just enrage users.

Comment: It is a duplicate because its still being caused by the same fundamental problem but I'm not going to fight you over it. The real moral of this story is that arrays and generics do not play well together. Better to use collections.

Comment: See [Array of Generic Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3975913/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/1393766

Comment: Possible way around would be creating `class FooE extends Foo<E>{}` and use it like `FooE[] fooArray = new FooE[8];` but that should be really last resort. Preferred way would be using `List<Foo<E>>`

Comment: @JimGarrison that's not the problem.

Comment: OK, please explain how this question is different.

Answer (score 2):

The *make-it-compile* way would be declaring the variable using generics but initializing **the array** (not the elements) using raw type:

```
//add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to avoid warnings
Foo<String>[] arrayOfFoo = new Foo[8];
arrayOfFoo[0] = new ClassThatImplementsFoo<String>();
//line below gives a compile error since the array declaration is for Foo<String>
//and won't allow Foo<AnotherClass>
arrayOfFoo[1] = new ClassThatImplementsFoo<Integer>();
```

A better and safer approach would be using `List` instead of plain array:

```
List<Foo<String>> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo<String>>();
fooList.add(new ClassThatImplementsFoo<String>());
```

---

In your code, you should do this:

```
public class MyClass<E> {
    private final Foo<E>[] fooArray = new Foo[8];
    // (...)
}
```

Comment: The raw type approach is inherently bad (you should never use raw types). The list approach is better. I wouldn't label the first one as "correct".

Comment: I do NOT know the type in advance. See my edit!

Comment: @arshajii sadly, Java doesn't provide another compilable way to **initialize** the array. Note that the elements in the array cannot be initialized as `ClassThatImplementsFoo<Integer>` or another object.

Comment: @chrisapotek the solution applies as well if you use generics. Try it first.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Your suggestion gives a warning (rawtype). Is that normal, expected?

Comment: @chrisapotek I explained in my answer how to avoid the warning (that only notifies you're using a raw type). Seriously, seems that you only read the code and not the content of the answer.

Comment: Is your explanation to suppress de warning with the annotation?