# Java 2D array of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a 2D matrix of size nXm for which each cell contains an unknown number of values of type Integer(therefore I have to use a List to be able to dynamically add stuff, and have to use a 2D array nXm because arrays are easy to access and write code). 
Pl

- ease before recommend me any other data structure answer my question below and then discuss why I should not this and go for what you think will work better and more efficient:

**How can I allocate memory to the variable below**?

```
 ArrayList<Integer>[][] i2DArrayList;
```

I know at some points I have to do this. However prior to that I have to do some other memory allocation that I don't  remember know. Could you guide me in this matter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                i2DArrayList[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
    }
}
```

I already know how to do it in 1D:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] i1DArrayList;

i1DArrayList = new ArrayList[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < i1DArrayList.length; i++) {
        i1DArrayList[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
```

Comment: I think you want an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Comment: No like I said I am fine with ArrayList<Integer>[][] i2DArrayList

Comment: Unfortunately [you can't create array with generic type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104). I hope you will end up with `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` since it is the best approach for you.

Comment: I edited my question @Pshemo : I already know how to do it in 1D ...

Comment: @Cgraphics But this will lead to type safety issues. If you want to ignore them then OK, it's your choice.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Simply use a multidimensional array initializer:</strike>

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] i2DArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>[n][m];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] i2DArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
    i2DArrayList[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>[m];
}
```

Java do not let you *allocate* generic arrays. That is, you cannot make a `new T[]` or `new List<T>[]`. The reason is that arrays also store their element type to allow type checking elements at run-time. However, type erasure removes these generic types at compile-time and thus no valid element type can be assigned to a `new T[]` or `new List<T>[]`. There are some solutions though:

- Use some `Collection` type to store the matrix as well. For example:

  ```
  List<List<List<Integer>>> i2DArrayList = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();
  ```

  However, this gets ugly really fast.
- You can make your own, non-generic entry class:

  ```
  class Entry {
      final List<Integer> entries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  Entry[][] i2DArrayList = new Entry[n][m];
  ```
- If you know your matrix is sparse, you can use a `Map<Position, List<Integer>>` instead, with `Position` a value class with `x` and `y` fields.

Comment: Dammit, Java and its crappy generics again.

Comment: Not a problem of generics...

Comment: Updated my answer. @Legend, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The generics for your previous answer were fine. Not perfect, seeing as you don't have to specify the generics in the constructor. The code just wouldn't work.

Comment: @Legend No, previous version of answer wouldn't compile because of generics. Java wont something like `new ArrayList<Integer>[n][]`. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810074/array-of-generic-list)

Comment: @Legend Exactly, I fell for that pitfall at first. Here's [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2927427/1321716) demonstrating why you *cannot* do that. What other error where you seeing?