# C++ vector, java array equivalent?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, vector

In c++ we can have this kind of vectors:

```
vector < int > v[20];
```

I have to create the equivalent in java of a program in c++. I can declare

```
static ArrayList < ArrayList<Integer > > v;
```

but it's not quite what I want. I want it to be more intuitive.
I am trying to find a way to easily add elements in my structure.
For example if I have a graph and I am reading a road from a to b, in C++ a simply use v[a].push_back(b).

Comment: `vector<int> v[20]` is **not** a vector of vectors.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810074/array-of-generic-list
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Vector;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Vector<Integer>[] anArray = (Vector<Integer>[]) new Vector[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
           anArray[i] = new Vector<Integer>();
        anArray[2].add(2);//....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `vector<int> v[20]` is not vectors of vector.

Secondly [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) could be the equivalent of `std::vectors` in Java.

The general equivalent of `vector.push_back` could be like this ie, using generic list:-

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
x.add(1);
```

Comment: This is what I have in C++ :
 for(int i = 1; i<=m ; i++)
    {
        in>>a>>b;
        v[a].push_back(b);
    }
I can not use add as you said!

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer>[] v = (List<Integer>[]) Array.newInstance(Integer.class, 20);
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; ++i) {
            v[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

Sadly, Java is not so concise or well designed here. `Array.newInstance` serves for all dimesions: `int[][][]` would be `Array.newInstance(int.class, 10, 10, 10)`. Hence it returns an Object as least denominator, and needs to be cast.

The initial array contains only nulls, and needs an initialisation.

***Correction:***

Should of course be `List.class` not `Integer.class`.

Comment: Why `Integer.class`, specifically? I mean, is there a technical reason, is it common convention, or just your personal preference?

Comment: You mean int being a primitive type, Integer the object wrapper. `List<int>` is not possible, a List contains objects only. There are non-standard libraries for an int list. However with boxing you may put an int into the list etcetera.

Comment: **Sorry**, should have been `List.class`.