# How do I implement a hashmap using generics? (Issue with not being able to create generic arrays)

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

this is what I have so far, but I'm having trouble with one line:

```
public class SFHashMap<Key, Value> {
    private static int size;
    private Entry<Key, Value>[] table;

    class Entry<Key, Value> {
        Key key;
        Value value;
        Entry next;

        public Entry(Key key, Value value, Entry<Key, Value> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public SFHashMap() {
        this(16);
    }

    public SFHashMap(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        table = new Entry[size]; **HERE**
    }
}
```

for `table = new Entry[size];`, I can't instantiate it as `new Entry<Key, Value>[size]` because I can't create generic arrays. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: consider using `Set<Entry<Key, Value>>` instead of an array.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23141780/2891664) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26927233/2891664). (Also looks like `class Entry` should probably be `static class Entry` in your case.)