# How can I create an array of objects of a generic class?

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

I builded a class to act like a queue. And I called it SalehQueue of Generic type. How can I create an array of that class?

```
  SalehQueue<String> department=new SalehQueue<String>();
```

Can I do this?

```
  SalehQueue[]<String> department=new SalehQueue[10]<String>();
```

Any idea??

Comment: Use a `List<SelehQueue<String>>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a generic array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141696/create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7810074/2891664 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/217065/2891664

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, instatiate an Array of objects.

If you cant create generic typed arrays, just omit the generic type on instantiation.

```
List<String>[] stringss = new ArrayList[10];
```

Comment: *"instatiate an Array of objects"* This doesn't make sense. Read the question again.

Comment: It does not work with me. I tried  SalehQueue[]<String> department=new SalehQueue[10]<String>();   And SalehQueue<String>[] department=new SalehQueue<String>[10]; Same problem.

Comment: I told instiate array of objects, because this is a ordinary object array.

Comment: Omit generic type after the new

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList <SalehQueue<String>> department=  new ArrayList <SalehQueue<String>>();
```

This is the  correct answer. Because Java does not support array in generic.

Answer (score 0):

When using `new` to create an array, the component type must be a refillable type.

You can create the array using the raw type:

```
SalehQueue<String>[] department = new SalehQueue[10];
```

or the type parameterized by all wildcards:

```
SalehQueue<String>[] department = (SalehQueue<String>[])new SalehQueue<?>[10];
```